# react-Post method only adding new "id" but data inside body tag not getting added

Tags: reactjs, post, react-hooks

I can see correct data added inside body tag POST method but in end url only id is getting added.
am i doing something wrong?

following is the output I am getting, data should like id:3, but in subsequent Post's only id is getting added.

```
{
id: "3",
title: "Greek Salad",
ingredients: [
"1 Onion",
"1 Block of Feta",
"Olives",
"Tomatoes",
"Olive Oil"
],
method: "Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse minima ex rem quis similique eum ratione quaerat, voluptas molestias ut repudiandae delectus voluptates. Eius esse at tenetur ab accusamus excepturi?",
cookingTime: "35 minutes"
},
{
id: "lXOYU8C"
},
{
id: "IacXVJs"
},
```

I am using following hook for get& post method.

```
const useFetch = (url, method="GET") => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [option, setOptions] = useState(null)

  const PostData = (info)=>{

    setOptions({
      method:"POST",
      header:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
      },
      body : JSON.stringify(info)
    })
  }

  const fetchData = async (fetchOptions) => {
    console.log("fetchOptions :",fetchOptions)
    try {
      setIsPending(true);

      const response = await fetch(url,{...fetchOptions});
      const databyresponse = await response.json();

      setIsPending(false);
      setData(databyresponse);
      setError(null);
    } catch (e) {
      setIsPending(false);

      console.log("error", e);

      setError(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    if(method == "GET"){
      
      fetchData();
    }
    if(method == "POST" && option){

      fetchData(option);

    }
  }, [url,option,method]);

  return { data, isPending, error, PostData };
};

export default useFetch;
```

and this is how i am calling my post method.

```
const  {data, isPending, error, PostData } = useFetch("http://localhost:3000/recipes", "POST");

 
  const [input, setInput] = useState({
    title: "",
    cookingTime: "",
    method: "",
  });
  const [ingtext, setIngtext] = useState("");
  const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);

  const IngredientInput = useRef(null);

  const onSubmithandler = (e) => {
    console.log("submitted");
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log({input,ingredients})
   let title = input.title;
   let cookingTime = input.cookingTime;
   let method = input.method;

    PostData({title,cookingTime,method,ingredients})
  };
```

Comment: I'm guessing that there is something to do with yout `JSON.stringify(info)` part, you can try to avoid the stringify or pass data in a more explicit way like `{title: input.title}` and so on

Comment: tried this `{title: input.title}` , but still same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should have been:

```
setOptions({
  methods:"POST",
   header: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(info)
})
```

the missing `s` in `methods` was the culprit.